# Selenium Firefox driver not receving data from URL with port

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using a Selenium Firefox WebDriver to receive data from a REST service at `http://localhost:5000/mywebpage`.

My web driver code is:

```
public class MyClass
{
     //Target URL http://localhost:5000/mywebpage
     private WebDriver driver;

     @Before
     public void setup()
     {
           driver=new FirefoxDriver();
     }

     @Test
     public void myTest()
     {
           driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/mywebpage"); //This will eventually timeout
           //If I setup my webserver to serve on port 80, everything works
           //e.g. driver.get("http://127.0.0.1/mywebpage");
     }
   ......
}
```

How do I get Selenium to retrieve the webpage I have at `my_url_here:5000/mywebpage`?

Comment: Are you hosting the website locally?

Comment: Well actually you are using 127.0.0.1. So yes my question is can you run the same test on IE or Chrome?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver. There is a property "Port" which you may need to set.

Comment: I added the port via System.setProperty(...) as suggested but this did not work. When I do driver.get("http://localhost:5000") it still times out.